# zimbra how to modify template js

Tags: templates, calendar, zimbra

I want to modify schedule item template file  (click Calendar, create new item and edit it)

So i modified zimbra/templates/calendar/Appointment.template.js  but nothing heppend after reload site.

Comment: I did some zimbra-ing a while ago, so I'm a bit rusty.  Did you compile the whole thing after changing that file? Sorry if it was a silly question.

Comment: what do you mean by compiling the whole thing ? is it restarting zimbra server ?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to modify a template, you have to include it in a skin and then use the "zmskindeploy"-Tool to deploy the skin and thus compile the template.

See the [Zimbra skin doku](http://files.zimbra.com/docs/skins/Themes.html%23workingwithtemplates) for references.

Comment: I restarted the server and the whole server and It doesn't take effect

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I did some reading and updated my answer.